# Preact router Property 'path' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes'

Tags: typescript, preact, preact-router

I am currently going through a problem whilst making a website of mine with preact router. whenever I try to put something in the router it has an error of Property 'path' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes'. But it doesn't stop the site from running but whenever I change the url to '/shop' it doesn't show anything.
shop function

```js
import { Item } from '../../Types/types'
import './item.css'
import Navbar from '../Navbar'
export default function Items(items:Array<Item>) {
    return (
    <>
    <Navbar />
    <div className='container'>
    {
    items.map( item => { 
    return ( 
    <div className='item'>
        <div>
            <h3>
                {item.name}
            </h3>
        </div>      
        <div className='itemimage'>
            <img src={item.picture} alt={item.name} />
        </div>
        <div>
            <strong>{item.price}</strong>
        </div>
    </div>
    )})
    }
    </div>
    </>
    )
}
```

and my router function

```js
import Router from 'preact-router'
import {App} from '../app'
import Items from './shop/items'
export const Route = () => {
    return (
    <Router>
    <App path='/' />
    <Items path='/shop' />  
    </Router>
    )
}
```

I tried following the tutorial on preact router. It did not work. I then tried to look up this problem there was nothing about this exact problem with preact-router.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an inherent limitation of TS, though there is an alternative which is the `<Route>` component, exported from `preact-router`:

```
import { Route, Router } from 'preact-router'
import { App } from '../app'
import Items from './shop/items'

export const RouteX = () => {
    return (
        <Router>
            <Route path="/" component={<App />} />
            <Route path="/shop" component={<Items />} />
        </Router>
    )
}
```

Essentially, the strictness of TS means that `<Router>` can't define its children as additionally taking a `path` prop. So instead of applying your path to the component directly, you will need to use a wrapper to appease TS.

> But it doesn't stop the site from running but whenever I change the url to '/shop' it doesn't show anything

It doesn't show anything as you're a) not using props correctly and b) not passing items to `<Items>`.

```js
export default function Items({ items: Array<Item> }) {
```

```
<Route path="/shop" component={<Items items={...} />} />
```

Props are always an object, so you'll need to destructure or access `.items` on your props object. As you're not providing `items` to `<Items>` though, your component has no data to work with.

Comment: thank you so much I genuinely couldn't find information on what you covered and I cant thatnk you enough

Comment: Ok now I changed the router and I'm met with Type 'Element' is not assignable to type 'AnyComponent<{ path: string; component: Element; }> & (Element | undefined)'.
  Type 'VNode<any>' is not assignable to type 'ComponentConstructor<{ path: string; component: Element; }, any> & Element'.
    Type 'VNode<any>' is not assignable to type 'ComponentConstructor<{ path: string; component: Element; }, any>'.
      Type 'VNode<any>' provides no match for the signature 'new (props: { path: string; component: Element; }, context?: any): Component<{ path: string; component: Element; }, any>'.

Comment: That's likely because you've named your component "Route" (which I didn't catch in my example, though it's been updated now). Change the name or show some code if that doesn't work.

Comment: I had reaized that and changed it but it still had not changed the error

Comment: https://pastebin.com/sFaCM5n4

Comment: alright I have looked into developer console and I am seeing things such as was blocked because of a disallowed MIME type (“”).

Comment: I jumped to js and its just working.